# Cloudera 5.6: Parquet does not support date. See HIVE-6384

Tags: hive, cloudera, parquet

I am currently using Cloudera 5.6 trying to create a parquet format table in hive table based off another table, but I am running into an error.

```
create table sfdc_opportunities_sandbox_parquet like 
sfdc_opportunities_sandbox STORED AS PARQUET
```

Error Message

```
Parquet does not support date. See HIVE-6384
```

I read that hive 1.2 has a fix for this issue, but Cloudera 5.6 and 5.7 do not come with hive 1.2.  Has anyone found way around this issue?

Comment: I guess by that time you've figure out? If you can use a spark dataframe there is no issue, but myself I need to use Hive in certain scenarios, and I found no workaround except writting `long` types and then converting in a `view`.

Comment: Make you date column either as string or timestamp. No other options I think.

Comment: I've been using timestamp for a year now.

Comment: Assume you're still having to use `timestamp`?

Comment: We are on a newer version of CDH, but we haven’t change the ETL processes, so yes we still use timestamp. But we are slowly moving off CDH

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Except from using an other data type like [TIMESTAMP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-Date/TimeTypes) or an other storage format like [ORC](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC), there might be no way around if there is a dependency to the used Hive version and Parquet file storage format.

According Clouderas [CDH 5 Packaging and Tarball Information](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_vd_cdh_package_tarball.html), the whole branch 5 comes packed with [Apache Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) in v1.5.0 and [Apache Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) in v1.1.0.

Date was implemented in ParquetSerde with [HIVE-8119](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8119) and as of Hive 1.2.

Comment: Yeah, I have been using timestamp as a work around for a year now