# Date datatype not supported in hive1.1 with parquet format?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using hive 1.1 from cloudera CDH5.5

When I try to create a hive internal table as below I get the below error .

```
hive> create table acct_IK(acct_id int,acct_name String,trans_dt date)
> stored as parquet;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Parquet does not support date. See HIVE-6384
```

Do I need to upgrade hive to next version?
How do I create a table with date datatype in that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloudera 5.6: Parquet does not support date. See HIVE-6384](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357009/cloudera-5-6-parquet-does-not-support-date-see-hive-6384)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was noted in [HIVE-6384](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6384), Date is supported only from hive 1.2.0